# MongoDB update multiple collections

Tags: mongodb

My mongo db contains following collections name like

```
10.9.40.46
10.9.40.47
10.9.40.48
10.9.40.49
10.9.40.50
10.9.40.51
10.9.40.52
```

In all collections having N numbers of documents and every documents had common key name as "status" by default all documents had "status" 1, When I update my collections to change "status" 1 to 0 I use following query

```
 db.getCollection("10.9.40.46").update({"status":1},{$set:{"status":0}},false,true)
```

The above query work fine but, I want update all my collections then I pass my collections name to query manually, So there is any concepts in MongoDB that I used database and update all collections documents in that database using single query or something like that? I also used looping to read all collections and update documents but I it takes long time because of large number of collections.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is no API to perform the same operation on multiple collections with a single command. That's because you normally don't use collections the way you use them. Collections are used to group documents of the same type, not for grouping them based on content and/or key.

The normal way to organize the documents you have would be to put them all in one collection, add a field for the IP address to each document and create an index on the ip-field for faster lookup.

Comment: I would say collections are "typically", but not always used to group documents of the same type.  There are cases where it's worthwhile putting disparate types in the same collection. #minorNit

Comment: If I put all collections documents in single collection then my single collection increase size, and my code worked like every 5min. I put new data in collections so how single collections handled this situations there may be problem like write lock?

Comment: @yogesh Collection size should not be a problem. MongoDB is designed to scale to huge collection sizes. Write-locks are per-database, not per-collection. So using more collections doesn't reduce the likeliness of an operation getting delayed because of a write-lock. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/ for more information on database locks in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

you can use  for loop for the same.

```
var collection='10.9.40.'
var count=46;
var n=46;
var url='';
for(i =0;i<7;i++){
url="";
n=46+i;
url=count+n;
db.getCollection(url).update({"status":1},{$set:
{"status":0}},false,true)
}
```